# Android - Best practice Login application

Tags: android, authentication

I want to build an application with register/login modules and I want to know how to handle login session with Android. I have a Django API server side. Users may be logged in to perform some specific actions (for example see their profiles).

What is the best way to do something like that ? (I know how to develop with Android but I wonder how to design these such of feature)

Thank you.

Comment: Database is local or server side ?

Comment: you have cookies manger in url connection which can handle sessions for 2.3+ and can impliment session in appache http client by parsing the header and then appending it i hope session is the normal procedure for security in any web based services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be various ways some of them are:

i. GoogleAuthUtil API is one that allows user to authenticate using the Gmail User account to which the User has registered its phone i.e. the Google Play Account. This will omit the requirement of creating a login screen and authentication.

For further information look at:

http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android.html

ii. Make your own login screen and authenticate the username and password and store it inside the internal FileSystem. Once you want to communicate with the server retreive this information from this file and send it to the server.

The first one will depend on using google Services API. In this case you dont have to worry about registering the user...Forgot your passwords and all sort of stuff that you would require to build on a login screen.

Whereas the second approach will be independent and specific to your application only. The advantage is you will have full control but you will have to manage all the small bits and pieces yourself.